# Why does xelatex produce different files from the same deterministic sources?

Tags: xetex

Take the simple latex source file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsgen}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

When processed with "latex" you always get the same DVI file, identical everywhere except for the date.

When processed (multiple times) with "pdflatex" you get the same PDF file, with the exception of an ID and the Date, and the same thing for "lualatex".

But when processed (multiple times) with "xelatex" you get wildly different PDF files, with different sizes. One can see the differences easily with "vimdiff".

Why is it the processing with "xelatex" not deterministic - not the same for the same sources?

Comment: I get no visual changes with `xelatex`. The pdf filesize oscillates between `10727`, `10728`, or `10729` bytes. Thus "wildly different" definitely does not apply on my system (mac os x). Which OS do you use? From which editor do you compile the source?

Comment: `vimdiff` indeed indicates differences inside the `pdf`. Perhaps something having to do with font compression. Needs a pdf expert here.

Comment: XeTeX produces exactly the same `xdv` files on multiple runs, _i.e._ their TeX contents are the same. Where's the issue here? (`xdvipdfmx` and `dvipdfmx` both produce some variation in the find PDF file but as already commented this is likely to do with font compression.)

Comment: Or you are actually embedding different fonts which just happen to have the same name

Comment: @AFeldman: That's wrong: luatex does _not_ claim to be 100% compatible to TeX.

Comment: @AFeldman We are not talking about a run of xelatex producing the same file as a run of pdflatex!!! We are talking about multiple runs of xelatex on the same files, that is: running "xelatex file.tex" repeated time!

Comment: @jfbu The differences on TL 2015 under Linux are much bigger. The file sizes varies to + or - 10 bytes approximately and even though the sizes are approximately the same, the files differ in way more than 10 places. Just run "xelatex file.tex" and compare them with vimdiff.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue is related to the driver: xdvipdfmx.
In order to generate unique tags for fonts,
random number is used.
Try

```
xelatex -no-pdf test

xdvipdfmx test.xdv
pdffonts test.pdf
```

The tag will change like

```
LYKESP+CMR10
CBIVMK+CMR10
...
```

each time you run

```
xdvipdfmx test.xdv
```

Comment: But this doesn't explain the difference in size, does it?

Comment: @Robert: The data are compressed by zlib as a stream.
Different data may be compressed differently.

Comment: @AkiraKakuto Indeed this is the core of the problem, but I still do not understand why "xdvipdfmx" needs to generate a "unique" tag per font! Aren't these fonts uniquely identified by their names?

Comment: @Paulo Ney: I'm not an expert for fonts.
I think authors of the driver considered that a subset of
a font should be named differently.

Comment: It’s a very old practice to prepend tags to subsetted fonts embedded in PostScript and PDF files.  I think it was a recommendation early on (probably because the embedded font, being a subset, is formally not the same as the full font).

Comment: @ArthurReutenauer I understand the fact that the tag has to be introduced for the subsetting -- the point here is why this tag is a random string as opposed to a deterministic string based on the subset of a particular font? It is very unfortunate someone decided to make it random -- and I still have no idea what purpose it serves!

Comment: @PauloNey: In TeX Live 2016, you will obtain exactly the same pdf file
from a unique xdv file, if you define an environment variable
`SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH` correctly like `SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH=1456304492`.
The name of an output pdf file must be the same.

Comment: @PauloNey Nobody decided to make it random on purpose.

Answer (score 9):

What seems to differ is the actual binary encodings of some parts. I trust that the pdf rendering does not vary at all. In my experience the file size changed only by plus or minus 1 byte (mac os x). I have done an ediff in hexadecimal mode of two such pdf's, here is a snapshot of where the first differences appear:

> [image: Blockquote]

This first difference thus occurs in a part of the pdf relative to the partially embedded font. I don't know what causes this.

Generally speaking I can imagine that if you have say some 213 bytes thing which must be stored in 256 bytes, then the last 43 bytes may be random memory, if moreover one or many such things together are compressed then you get varying result. On undecompressing, there will be some varying random junk after structures terminators (or after a given number of bytes). Like non-coding DNA. Which perhaps is not so much non-coding, but let's not digress.

Only someone familiar with XeTeX source code can answer convincingly I guess.

Don't worry about the `C-M-'` undefined, I was trying to capture the thing via keyboard shortcuts I had forgotten.

Comment: I have to admit that you flying over my head right now and I have not fully understood the meaning of everything you said ... nonetheless even if it is the compression if a font -- why would it compress differently on different runs? I still would expect the whole process to be deterministic and compress in exactly the same way.